# Problema com a calculadora em Go [INICIANTE]

Tags: golang, matemática

Gente, sou iniciante na programação e estou tentando praticar fazendo uma calculadora em Go. Alguém sabe me explicar porque quando tento calcular, os resultados estão me retornando sempre o 0? Eu estou esquecendo de retornar algo? Não consigo entender o que eu estou deixando passar.

```go
    func menu() {
    
        fmt.Println("Qual operação deseja fazer?")
    
        fmt.Println("1) Soma? ")
        fmt.Println("2) Subtração? ")

    
    }
    
    func main() {
        var num1, num2, resposta int
        var soma int = num1 + num2
        var subtracao int = num1 - num2
    
        fmt.Println("Bem-vindo(a) a calculadora!")
    
        fmt.Println("Digite o valor do primeiro número: ")
        fmt.Scanln(&num2)
    
        fmt.Println("Digite o valor do segundo número: ")
        fmt.Scanln(&num2)
    
        menu()
        fmt.Scanln(&resposta)
        switch resposta {
        case 1:
            fmt.Println(soma)
        case 2:
            fmt.Println(subtracao)
        default:
            fmt.Println("Número inválido!")
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está realizando as operações antes mesmo de obter as entradas, então o go utiliza os valores inciais das variáveis para obter o resultado.

Outro erro no seu código é que você está lendo as entradas na variável `num2` oq vai acabar sobreescrevendo a mesma.

```golang
func main() {
        var num1, num2, resposta int
        //soma e subtracao tem que ir para depois de obter as entradas
        var soma int = num1 + num2
        var subtracao int = num1 - num2
    
        fmt.Println("Bem-vindo(a) a calculadora!")
    
        fmt.Println("Digite o valor do primeiro número: ")
        fmt.Scanln(&num2) // aqui deveria ser num1
    
        fmt.Println("Digite o valor do segundo número: ")
        fmt.Scanln(&num2)
    
        menu()
        fmt.Scanln(&resposta)
        switch resposta {
        case 1:
            fmt.Println(soma)
        case 2:
            fmt.Println(subtracao)
        default:
            fmt.Println("Número inválido!")
        }
    
    }
```

Outra coisa que vc tem que pensar é que vc ta fazendo todas as operações mesmo não sendo necessárias, o que é um desperdício de processamento. Seria mais interessante as operações estarem dentro do switch junto da impressão do resultado.

Comment: Valeu cara, isso já me deu uma luz!

Answer (score -1):

Outra sugestão é:
Colocar as variáveis soma e subtração dentro do "case" respectivo:

```
switch resposta (){
case 1:
 var soma int = num1 + num2
 fmt.Println(soma)
case 2:
 var subtracao int = num1 - num2
 fmt.Println(subtracao)
default:
fmt.Println("Número inválido)
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).